# How to create .krb and .kfb fipes in PYKE

Tags: python, pyke

I am new to pyke, hence i don't know how to create these files. Can such files be made in notepad++ and also can PYKE be used to create and dietician expert system

Comment: It appears that .krb ad .kbf files must be plain text files; the docs explain their syntax. Notepad++ should be adequate.

Comment: thanks...do you know further about pyke

Comment: No, it's the first time I see PYKE. It seems to be a Prolog implementation with a Pythonic syntax, so ideas from most Prolog books should apply.

Answer (score 0):

Your favorite text editor will work. Simply make the extension krb/kfb/kqb.

PyKE is an inference engine used with Python. Because this introduces logic programming to Python, you have the ability to create an expert system, just like in Prolog or CLIPS. So yes, you can create a diet planner or anything else.

Also, PyKE was inspired by Prolog, but it tries to go beyond what Prolog is capable of. For one, it can use both forward chaining and backward chaining, while Prolog is backward only. Another idea that sets it apart from Prolog is the ability to generate new programs from Python functions in the PyKE code that are added when the rule they are attached to is fired.